# Use Azure Stream Analytics Managed Identity to access SQL DB using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-stream-analytics, azure-managed-identity

There is an option to create Managed Identity from terraform for Stream analytics job (`azurerm_stream_analytics_job`, using identity block).

And it is possible to use Managed Identity to connect to databases (as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/sql-database-output-managed-identity?tabs=azure-sql))

But I could not find how to use managed identity to create input using `azurerm_stream_analytics_reference_input_mssql`

UPDATE:

To be clear, thats what I am after:
[image]
And then
[image]

Comment: [Support for Azure Stream Analytics Reference Input MSSQL](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/9231) and [New resource azurerm_stream_analytics_reference_input_mssql](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/13822)

Comment: [azurerm_stream_analytics_reference_input_mssql - Example Usage](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/034da45ed8634aaff1a485ad3f0e3a5ec30532fa/website/docs/r/stream_analytics_reference_input_mssql.html.markdown#example-usage)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT thanks for the links, but I am interested in managed identity specifically. As I understand, those examples have username and password as required fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**As Per July 2022**

It does not look like terraform is supporting it (see [documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/stream_analytics_reference_input_mssql)).

With this arm template, I was able to deploy (`"authenticationMode": "Msi"`):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "streamAnalyticsJobName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "streamAnalyticsJobNameInputName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "sqlServerName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "databaseName": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.StreamAnalytics/streamingjobs/inputs",
      "apiVersion": "2017-04-01-preview",
      "name": "[format('{0}/{1}', parameters('streamAnalyticsJobName'), parameters('streamAnalyticsJobNameInputName'))]",
      "properties": {
        "type": "Reference",
        "datasource": {
          "type": "Microsoft.Sql/Server/Database",
          "properties": {
            "authenticationMode": "Msi",
            "server": "[parameters('sqlServerName')]",
            "database": "[parameters('databaseName')]",
            "refreshType": "Static",
            "fullSnapshotQuery": "SELECT Id, Name, FullName\nFrom dbo.Device\nFOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF @snapshotTime --Optional, available if table Device is temporal"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

So you could always use `azurerm_template_deployment` resource to deploy using terraform.

Comment: Yes, sorry if my question is not very clear. Is it possible to use terraform (azurerm_stream_analytics_reference_input_mssql) to connect to database using Managed Identity?

Comment: It is not supported by Azure for the moment so it can't be done using terraform.

Comment: It is supported by Azure - Reference Input - SQL Database

Comment: have you check my link ? only reference data and outputs support managed identity  not inputs.

Comment: Yes, I might be unclear with wording. I am after Reference Input. I updated my question with screenshots from the portal

Comment: oh ok, just saw your edit, will have a look then. sounds like it is possible but the documentation is not up to date

Comment: @JoeBloggs let me know if that make more sense for you.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much
I'll keep the question open for a bit, but it looks like your solution is the only option for now